# Fix Syntax error: unexpected end of file in a "for loop"

Tags: bash, shell-script, for

So I tried to fix this problem by myself for a couple of hours but I couldn't 
here's the code block that has a problem I changed it, rewritten, I even tried to "do" only echo after each line but it doesn't seem to work. It is a code to decrypt CSV files of a game for some event thing. In case u want, here's full code https://pastebin.com/Gv3Fvyxy

```
for path in $(find assets -name "*.csv")
    do 
    f=$(echo "$path" | rev | cut -d"/" -f1 | rev)
    (
        dd if=$path bs=1 count=9 status=none
        dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 count=4 status=none
        dd if=$path bs=1 skip=9 status=none
    ) | lzma -dc -f > "decrypted/"$f

    done
```

Comment: Possibly your file has MS-DOS CRLF line delimiters?

Comment: It would be easier to compute`f` as `f=$( basename "$path" )` and safer to to call the loop with `-exec` from `find` than to rely on filenames being nice.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem. In the full code, the `-n` option is never checked: if appears in a block that is executed only if `-h` has been given but there is an `exit` before it. That full code also has an extra space after `"extracted/"`.

Comment: Install and use `shellcheck`. And quote every variable expansion. Especially, why quote the constant string `decrypted/` but not the expansion `$f` after it?

Comment: What shell is this run in? Shellcheck won't do a full check unless you provide a shebang. The name `path` is reserved in some shells as some kind of alias for `PATH` -- best not use it.

Answer (score 1):

An enhanced version of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

find assets -name '*.csv' -exec bash -c '
    f="$(awk '{print $NF}' <<< "$1")"
    {
        dd if="$1" bs=1 count=9 status=none
        dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 count=4 status=none
        dd if="$1" bs=1 skip=9 status=none
    } | lzma -dc -f > "decrypted/$f"

' -- {} \;
```

- take care of files with spaces in names
- simplify `rev|cut|rev` by [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)
- use more quotes !

Learn how to quote properly in shell, it's very important :

> "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
>   http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
>   http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
>   http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

Answer (score 0):

You don't show here the same version of script that you posted to pastebin.

The [pastebin code](https://pastebin.com/Gv3Fvyxy) has this line (57):

```
    f= $(echo "$path" | rev | cut -d "/" -f1 | rev)
```

In which there is an space after the `=`, that is a syntax problem.

Probably it is there (or close to it) that your script is failing.

And, in fact, that whole line could be simplified to:

```
    f=${path##*/}
```

But you also have **many** small code errors. Most of them could be detected and resolved by following the recommendations from [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/). Paste your script there and clean it up.

A cleaned-up version may look as:

```
#!/bin/bash

Usage(){ echo "Usage: $0 [-n filename.apk]"; exit; }

case $1 in
    -h) Usage;;
    -n) if [ -z "$2" ];then
        echo "You need to insert a filename"
        Usage
    fi
    filename=$2
    ;;
    *)  echo "Give me the clash royale filename"
        read -r filename
    ;;
esac

if [ ! -f "$filename" ];then
    echo "File \"$filename\" not found!"; exit
fi

#Unzipping
echo "Unzipping crash royale apk"
unzip -o -q "$filename" -d "extracted"

#Decrypting
echo "Decrypting csv files"
mkdir decrypted
find assets -name '*.csv' -exec bash -c '
    f="${1##*/}"
    {
        dd if="$1" bs=1 count=9 status=none
        dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 count=4 status=none
        dd if="$1" bs=1 skip=9 status=none
    } | lzma -dc -f > "decrypted/$f"

' sh {} \;

echo "All the decrypted file are stored in the decrypted folder"

#Delete partial files
rm -r extracted
```